# Add dragula Attribut on buttonclick

Tags: html, angular, typescript, dragula, ng2-dragula

I'm at the moment working with Angular (4.0) and ng2-dragula. I've mad a `div` to a dragula container to move the items in it like this:

```
<div id="dragcontainer" [dragula]='"first-bag"'>
```

Now I'd like to implement the function to make my div to a dragable dragula div on button click. For example:

Before button click:

```
<div id="dragcontainer">
```

After button click:

```
<div id="dragcontainer" [dragula]='"first-bag"'>
```

I've tried this:

HTML-Button:

```
<button md-raised-button style="margin-left: 20px;" (click)="dragable()">
    Make it drawable
</button>
```

TypeScipt Code:

```
dragable(): void {
    document.getElementById("dragcontainer").setAttribute("[dragula]", "first-bag");
}
```

but that's not working. To ensure that I've used the `.setAttribute` command correctly I've tried this:

```
dragable(): void {
    document.getElementById("dragcontainer").setAttribute("align", "center");
}
```

and that was working.

Has anybody tried this before or does anybody know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need some boolean flag in the controller that is triggered after button click, you should listen on `drakeService.on('drag', listener)` and if flag is set to `false` (initially) then you immediately trigger `.cancel(true)` method.

Would be much easier I think if you could provide some online demo (plunkr for example).